# In abscence of move constructor the copy constructor is called ? Why is that?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-constructor

I am reading on C++11 and I had the following question. Suppose I have the following rough code

```
class foo
{
public:
    foo()
    {std::cout << "Regular constructor \n";}

    foo(const foo& a) 
    {std::cout << "Copy constructor \n";}

    foo& operator=(const foo& a) 
    {std::cout << "Copy Assignment operator \n";}

    foo(foo&& a)
    {
        std::cout << "Move constructor \n";
    }

    foo& operator=(foo&& a) 
    {std::cout << "Move Assignment operator \n";}

    int a;
};


foo myfunction()
{
    foo d;
    d.a =120;
    return d;
}
```

Now if I do something like this

```
foo a = myfunction();
```

I know that the move constructor will be called since myfunction() returns an rvalue type.
Now I noticed that if I remove the move constructor code from my class then the copy constructor is called. My question is why does that happen ? If the return type of myfunction is foo&& and copy constructor takes in a foo& then why is the copy constructor being called ? I am using Vs2012.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per paragraph §12.8/9 of the C++11 Standard:

> If the definition of a class `X` does not explicitly declare a move constructor, one will be implicitly declared as defaulted if and only if
>
> > — **`X` does not have a user-declared copy constructor,**
> > — `X` does not have a user-declared copy assignment operator,
> > — `X` does not have a user-declared move assignment operator, and
> > — `X` does not have a user-declared destructor.

Since you have a user-declared copy-constructor, the move-constructor is inaccessible and it falls back to invoking the copy-constructor.

> If the return type of `myfunction` is `foo&&` and copy constructor takes in a `foo&` then why is the copy constructor being called?

Two things wrong here: `myfunction` returns a `foo` by value, not a `foo&&`. Furthermore, your constructor takes `const foo&` which can in fact bind to rvalues  (which is not what's happening here).

Comment: Bingo. For further reading, [the rule of 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782757/rule-of-three-becomes-rule-of-five-with-c11).

Comment: when you say `Furthermore, your constructor takes const foo& which can in fact bind to rvalues ` could you explain that a little more ?

Comment: @Rajeshwar You said your constructor takes a `foo&` which isn't true. You wrote it as `foo(const foo&)`. The language allows rvalues to bind to references to `const` (i.e. `int const& r = 100`). But the value that is being returned from `myfunction` is an lvalue, not an rvalue.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up. Now i am confused as to why the move constructor gets called (if it is present) incase of `foo a = myfunction();` if a lvalue is being returned from the function?

Comment: @Rajeshwar No, I said the return value `d` was an lvalue. It was being copy-constructed by the return type `foo`. `myfunction` returns by value so it is a temporary that is returned (an rvalue). If a move-constructor is available and viable it will be chosen for the initialization of `a` because is a better match than a copy-constructor (for rvalues that is).

Comment: @Rajeshwar Just want to make sure you understand: `myfunction()` returns an rvalue (because it returns by value). Depending on whether or not the return value is an lvalue or rvalue, the value in the return statement will either be copy or move constructed from the return type. When it comes to `foo a = myfunction()`, since `myfunction()` is an rvalue, and `foo` has an available move constructor, it will be move constructed into `a`.

Answer (score 7):

> If the return type of myfunction is `foo&&`

But it isn't! The return type is `foo`. And `const foo&` happily binds to a `foo` rvalue.

Hint: "rvalue" and "rvalue reference" are two related, but distinct concepts. (Remember that C++ already had rvalues for decades before rvalue references were introduced into the language.)

Comment: could you explain `. And const foo& happily binds to a foo rvalue.` in a little more detail. Are you stating that the function actually returns a `foo` type that gets caught by the move constructor `foo&&` first ?

Comment: `foo` binds to `const foo&` if it is not temporary or to `foo&&` if it is temporary. If the compiler does copy-on-return optimization, you are in fact initializing `foo a` with `d`, that has a name (and hence is not temporary)

Comment: @Rajeshwar I am not sure what you are asking. It has always been the case in C++ that if you return by value, then you have an rvalue, and const references have always been able to bind to them. "rvalue" does *not* imply "rvalue reference" or "move constructor".